# Matplotlib: Keeping the zoom while changing the image doesn't work

Tags: python, image-processing

I use matplotlib and an update function that triggers on a key press in order to cycle through a number of images in a specific folder.

here is part of my update function:

```
# skipping through the images with a and d
if event.key == "d":
    if photoIndex == numberOfPhotos-1:
        photoIndex = 0
    else:
        photoIndex += 1

elif event.key == "a":
    if photoIndex == 0:
        photoIndex = numberOfPhotos-1
    else:
        photoIndex -= 1

# Handle key press event
if event.key == "h":
    if equalizeHistogram == False:
        equalizeHistogram = True
    elif equalizeHistogram == True:
        equalizeHistogram = False

if event.key == "c":
    if calculateEdges == False:
        calculateEdges = True
    elif calculateEdges == True:
        calculateEdges = False

imagePath = imageFolder + os.listdir(imageFolder)[photoIndex]
unprocessedImage = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(imagePath), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

if equalizeHistogram == True:
    image = np.uint8(cv2.normalize(unprocessedImage, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX))

elif calculateEdges == False and equalizeHistogram == False:
    image = unprocessedImage

im.set_data(image)
```

I can change the index of the image (and therefore the image that gets displayed) with the 'a' and 'd' key. Since I use set_data(), the zoom level stays the same as it should be.

However, when I press the 'h' key to equalize the historgram it zooms out again?
I'm confused, since the only thing that I change is the 'image' variable which I also change when I cycle through the pictures.

So why is it, that using set_data() doesnt change the zoom in one instance, but does change the zoom in another instance?

I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

As answered to my question on the same subject (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63169926/8837809):

The key 'h', unlike 'a' and 'd', is part of matplotlib's [interactive navigation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/navigation_toolbar.html#navigation-keyboard-shortcuts) keys.

In order to avoid this problem, map the interactive navigation with other keys:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams["keymap.home"] = ['r', 'home']   # default value is ['h', 'r', 'home']
```